# notepad++ unable to install or update plugins with the new plugin admin

Tags: plugins, notepad++, text-editor

I installed notepad++ recently which came with the new plugin admin. After that I am unable to install new or update existing plugins.

Any idea what the issue could be? I tried "Run as administrator"and also pasting the dll directly to `C:\ProgramData\Notepad++\plugins` but nothing works.

Here are the app details.
Notepad++ v7.6.1   (64-bit)
Build time : Dec 12 2018 - 01:22:05
Path : C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
Admin mode : ON
Local Conf mode : OFF
OS : Windows 10 (64-bit)
Plugins : DSpellCheck.dll mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll

Comment: Plugin support in Notepad++ has been changed recently. There are many questions about this topic in the [Notepad++ forums](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/) where experts are providing support. I am sure your question has already been asked and answered there, so please read through before asking a new question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working with a 32-bit version. I was trying to install a 32-bit compatible plugin and that did not work with a 64-bit version.

I had to manually copy the dll to C:\ProgramData\Notepad++\plugins.

Answer (score 4):

1) to install plugins manually copy the dlls in folder \Plugins\ but stored in individual folders (having same name than file.dll)

note. plugin Admin place for plugins is C:\ProgramData\Notepad++\plugins

2)Plugin Admin, if you can see this entry in Menu, I understand you have the Setup version and during installation "Don't use %APPDATA%" checkbox was disabled.

You have to:

1. Tick the checkboxes of plugins to install
2. Click "Install"
3. Click "YES" when asking about restart the app

if this doesn't work, are you receiving any message?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, mine were caused by my company introducing WIndows 10 (64bit) and enforcing UAC.
Problem was, that proxy-information was not persisted in NPP, I also couldn't specify my proxy-credentials in the Updater-Proxy-dialog.

Solution was not using %APPDATA% during installation, then run NPP in administrator-mode (now proxy-credentials are persisted).

After restarting NPP in non-administrative mode, Plugin-Admin worked like charm.

Did a quick write-up here how to remedy this:
https://blog.2smart4u.de/2019/07/notepad-windows-10-uac-plugin-nightmare.html

Answer (score 0):

the default plugin folder has the dll. if you get it installed on another machine and can create the plug can copy the folder from that location, go back to old location, close the program then drop the folder in the default location then open up u should now see the plug in.